# Careers profile lists incorrect reputation points with linked Stack Overflow account

Tags: support, reputation, jobs, profile-page, openid

I (foolishly) have a [Careers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Careers) account with a [MyOpenID](http://myopenid.com/) login and a Stack Overflow account with a Stack Exchange login. They both have the same user name and e-mail, but something has gone wrong with the process of linking them.

My Careers profile says it's linked with what appears to be my Stack Overflow account, but the reputation points are wrong. My Stack Overflow account has `91` reputation points, and my Careers profile says I have `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Careers profile seems to be linked with another Stack Overflow profile.

I'm going to merge it into your current one and you should see the Careers profile update shortly after.

Comment: It seems like I have the same problem, there are 4days now (since i registered) that no updates took place (both sites and reputation wise). Could you please help me out with this one too?

Comment: @NikosMargaritis can you link me to your Careers profile?

Comment: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/210452 or http://careers.stackoverflow.com/nmargaritis . Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NikosMargaritis Your Careers profile is linked to the right SO profile, so unfortunately my ability to fix this up on ends there. Drop an email to careers@stackoverflow.com and they should be able to help you out further. Thanks!